# scssコンパイルができません

Tags: ruby, sass

環境
　windows10 ノートpc

https://www.monster-dive.com/blog/web_creative/20140407_000147.php
このサイトに沿ってsass環境をインストールしたのですが、コンパイルできません。
デスクトップでも同様の作業を行いましたがそちらは問題なく動きます。

具体的には

```
sass --watch C:\Users\------top.scss:C:\Users\\---------top.css
```

と打ち込んでも

```
>>> Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
      error No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - C:\Users\----1*
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - C:\Users\----*1
  Use --trace for backtrace.
```

上記のようなエラーが出る状態です。(----*にはuser名が入っています。)

一度ruby,sass共にアンインストールして、再インストールしてみましたが、まだこのエラーを吐き続けている状態です。
以前これとは違うエラーも吐かれましたが、その時とは違い、先頭に`Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.`とついています。

恥ずかしながら、Rubyなどさっぱりのぺーぺーもいいとこで、調べてはみたものの何が何だかさっぱりわからず、こちらで質問させていただきました。

原因と対処方法がわかる方、是非ご回答をお願い致します(><)

Answer (score 0):

`Users\`ではなく`Users\\`なのでは?

Comment: 増やしてみても、無理でした...。

Comment: ずっと調べていたところ、どうもrubyの最新バージョンが不安定なので、いくつか前のバージョンを使うと動くよ、という記事を見つけたので一度アンインストール、旧バージョンを再インストールしたところ、無事動きました...お騒がせ致しました(><)回答ありがとうございました!!

Comment: @Yamasaki rubyの最新バージョン、旧バージョンを可能であればそれぞれ具体的なバージョン番号も添えたうえで「自己回答」の形で記録を残してもらえると、他のユーザの助けになるかもしれません。